# Synchronizing between several git repos

Tags: git, version-control

I have a git repo that contains some code that compiles against several clones of well known open-source projects, such as Tensorflow, as well as others. Compiling different branches in my private repo requires different combinations of branches of the clones. For instance, Branch1 requires Branch_foo1 of repo foo and Branch_bar1 of repo bar. Many combinations are possible.

Is there a systematic way to reduce user error when switching branches? I would like to force a relationship between branches, such that switching a branch in my repo causes a switch in other repos as appropriate so that any compilation errors due to mismatched versions are avoided.

I would also like to do this without submodules, as my repo is much smaller than the public repos.
I would also like to avoid hardlinks, as I don't know in advance where a user might clone the repos to.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you’re using git as a dependency manager. Is that right?

Comment: I use git as version control. However, I'm looking for dependency management features, yes.

Comment: Git does not have dependency management features, and I wouldn't recommend trying to force it to do so either. Consider using a dependency manager based on the primary language/framework you use.